# How to access a view of parent fragment from child fragment in navigation component

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I need to access a view of parent fragment from child fragment.
[image]

I have a graph inside a fragment (my parent fragment) and i want to access a view that present in the parent fragment from child fragment, i'm using android navigation component, it's confused me a little bit.

Comment: use callback methods

Comment: @Himeshgoswami like making static callback?

Comment: let say Fragment 1 implement a callback interface and child Fragment will have that callback instance in has a relation then you can access fragment one inside your child fragment.

Comment: @Himeshgoswami ok i can create an interface in my Activity and Fragment1 will implement it and Fragment2 can call it from Activity using getActivity() method, it's ok but i want to directly access the view from Fragment2.

Comment: now by clicking you can call callback methods, and you can update view as needed.

Comment: @Himeshgoswami it's great, but as second solution :)

Comment: also have a look at my questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70721218/receive-fragment-result-in-navigation-component-fragment and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70680327/toolbar-icon-handling-using-navigation-component

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As i read your Explanation's You Know that ChildFragment Parent is NavHostFragment and NavHostFragment's Parent is ParentFragment.

```
NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getParentFragment();
Fragment parent = (Fragment) navHostFragment.getParentFragment();
parent.getView().findViewById(R.id.element_id);
```

*I have tried is my demo Project and work's for me.*

Comment: I tried so many answers but this one still works in 2022.

Comment: Didn't work for me ,parent of navhostfragment returns null

Comment: Hi @htafoya, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72482591) solved my problem, maybe you have use parentFragmentManager instead of childFragmentManager.

Answer (score 1):

**Using Activity:**

```
val buttonView = (context as Activity).findViewById<View>(R.id.map_list_card_view)
```

**Using Fragment:**

```
val parent: Fragment? = (parentFragment as NavHostFragment).parentFragment
val buttonView = parent?.view?.findViewById<View>(R.id.map_list_card_view)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ParentFragment parent = (ParentFragment) getParentFragment();
parent.getView().findViewById(R.id.your_element);
```

Comment: getParentFragment() method returns NavHostFragment, not my fragment.

Comment: i tried that before but got error, androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment cannot be cast to alistar.navigation.fragments.DashboardFragment

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {
    View view;
    ...
    ...

    public void setView(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }
}
```

And call `mFragment.setView()` before calling fragment transaction. I hope this helps!

Comment: i know that, but i'm using navigation component.

Comment: This is actually bad as sending View's as Argument cause memory leak's and cause Out of memory Exception's